# aws api gateway & lambda: multiple endpoint/functions vs single endpoint

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS api that proxies lamba functions. I currently use different endpoints with separate lambda functions:

```
api.com/getData --> getData
api.com/addData --> addData
api.com/signUp --> signUp
```

The process to manage all the endpoints and functions becomes cumbersome. Is there any disadvantage when I use a single endpoint to one lambda function which decides what to do based on the query string?

```
api.com/exec&func=getData --> exec --> if(params.func === 'getData') { ... }
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to map multiple methods to a single lambda function and many people are using this methodology today as opposed to creating an api gateway resource and lambda function for each discrete method.

You might consider proxying all requests to a single function. Take a look at the following documentation on creating an API Gateway => Lambda proxy integration:
[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource)

Their example is great here. A request like the following:

```
POST /testStage/hello/world?name=me HTTP/1.1
Host: gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
headerName: headerValue

{
    "a": 1
}
```

Will wind up sending the following event data to your AWS Lambda function:

```
{
  "message": "Hello me!",
  "input": {
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/hello/world",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "headerName": "headerValue",
      "Host": "gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "Postman-Token": "9f583ef0-ed83-4a38-aef3-eb9ce3f7a57f",
      "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/2.4.5",
      "Via": "1.1 d98420743a69852491bbdea73f7680bd.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "pn-PWIJc6thYnZm5P0NMgOUglL1DYtl0gdeJky8tqsg8iS_sgsKD1A==",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "54.240.196.186, 54.182.214.83",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "name": "me"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "hello/world"
    },
    "stageVariables": {
      "stageVariableName": "stageVariableValue"
    },
    "requestContext": {
      "accountId": "12345678912",
      "resourceId": "roq9wj",
      "stage": "testStage",
      "requestId": "deef4878-7910-11e6-8f14-25afc3e9ae33",
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
        "accountId": null,
        "cognitoIdentityId": null,
        "caller": null,
        "apiKey": null,
        "sourceIp": "192.168.196.186",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
        "userArn": null,
        "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/2.4.5",
        "user": null
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "apiId": "gy415nuibc"
    },
    "body": "{\r\n\t\"a\": 1\r\n}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
}
```

Now you have access to all headers, url params, body etc. and you could use that to handle requests differently in a single Lambda function (basically implementing your own routing).

As an opinion I see some advantages and disadvantages to this approach. Many of them depend on your specific use case:

- **Deployment**: if each lambda function is discrete then you can deploy them independently, which might reduce the risk from code changes (microservices strategy). Conversely you may find that needing to deploy functions separately adds complexity and is burdensome.
- **Self Description**: API Gateway's interface makes it extremely intuitive to see the layout of your RESTful endpoints -- the nouns and verbs are all visible at a glance. Implementing your own routing could come at the expense of this visibility.
- **Lambda sizing and limits**: If you proxy all -- then you'll wind up needing to choose an instance size, timeout etc. that will accommodate all of your RESTful endpoints. If you create discrete functions then you can more carefully choose the memory footprint, timeout, deadletter behavior etc. that best meets the needs of the specific invocation.

Comment: Great answer. The only advantage that would matter to me and that I did not think of is: Lambda sizing and limits. However, I think the advantages outweigh this factor. I might also split it into two endpoints catering different types of requests. 1. Simple DB queries with limited lambda ressources and 2. compute heavy functions with more powerful ressources.

Comment: Definitely. What's nice in 2017 is that they've made all the options available to us so we can pick the workflow that's best for our needs.

Comment: I'd like to add that one advantage of having just one Lambda Function is that it helps with cold starts and especially if you are using provisioned concurrency. One big function is more often warm and ready. And with PC you don't need to calculate different levels of PC for each function, but just one number for overall traffic.

Answer (score 34):

I would have commented to just add a couple of points to [Dave Maple's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620237/dave-maple?tab=profile) great answer but I don't have enough reputation points yet so I'll add the comments here.

I started to head down the path of multiple endpoints pointing to one Lambda function that could treat each endpoint different by accessing the 'resource' property of the Event.  After trying it I have now separated them into separate functions for the reasons that Dave suggested plus:

- I find it easier to go through logs and monitors when the functions are separated.
- One nuance that as a beginner I didn't pick up on at first is that you can have one code base and deploy the exact same code as multiple Lambda functions.  This allows you to have the benefits of function separation and the benefits of a consolidated approach in your code base.
- You can use the AWS CLI to automate tasks across the multiple functions to reduce/eliminate the downside of managing separate functions.  For example, I have a script that updates 10 functions with the same code.

Answer (score 27):

i've been building 5~6 microservices with Lambda-API Gateway, and been through several try & failure and success.

in short, from my experiences, it's better to delegate all the API calls to lambda with just one APIGateway wildcard mapping, such as

```
/api/{proxy+} -> Lambda
```

if you ever used any frameworks like [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) you know that when making APIs, features like
**"middleware"

"global exception handling"

"cascade routing"

"parameter validation"**
are really crucial.
as your API grows, it's almost impossible to manage all the routes with API Gateway mapping, nor API Gateway support non of those feature also.

further more, it's not really practically to break lambda for each endpoints for development or deployment.

from your example,

```
api.com/getData --> getData  
api.com/addData --> addData  
api.com/signUp --> signUp
```

imagine you have data ORM, User authentication logic, common view file (such as data.erb).. then how you gonna share that?

you might can break like,

```
api/auth/{+proxy} -> AuthServiceLambda  
api/data/{+proxy} -> DataServiceLambda
```

but not like "per endpoint". you might can lookup concept of microservice and best practice about how you can split the service

for those web framework like features, checkout [this](https://github.com/balmbees/corgi) we just built web framework for lambda since i needed this at my company.

Answer (score 20):

A similar scenario is adressed in the official AWS blogpost named [Best practices for organizing larger serverless applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/).

**The general recommendation is to split "monolithic lambdas" into separate lambdas and move the routing to the API Gateway.**

This is what the blog writes about the "monolithic lambda" approach:

> This approach is generally unnecessary, and it’s often better to take
> advantage of the native routing functionality available in API
> Gateway.
> ...
> API Gateway is also capable of validating parameters, reducing the
> need for checking parameters with custom code. It can also provide
> protection against unauthorized access, and a range of other features
> more suited to be handled at the service level.

Going from this:
[image: AWS app with monolithic lambda function]

To this

[image: AWS app with separate lambda functions]

Comment: thanks for linking this blog post. This approach makes the most sense to me, to split by resources. It seems this still implies that some of these lambdas would support multiple methods (ie GET/POST/PUT, etc) for each resource (opposed to a separate lambda per method). Initially I was doing a lambda per method which separates further but at an added build cost and template complexity (using AWS sam/cloud formation). One downside to this may be cold starts, since I think each lambda will have it's own container so the more lambdas the more cold starts)

Comment: Does the `/orders` Lambda handle GET, POST, PUT, etc requests in the same handler? Or would each method have a separate Lambda? And would that branch out in the API Gateway, or inside the "main" `/orders` Lambda?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Either way works well I believe. One factor that can help you to make a decision would be the size and scope of the `/orders` lambda.

Comment: There should not be cold starts if you set "Provisioned concurrency" to your lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html

Answer (score 5):

The responsibility of mapping API requests to Lambda in AWS is handled through a Gateway's API specification.

Mapping of URL paths and HTTP methods as well as data validation SHOULD be left up to the Gateway. There is also the question of permissions and API scope; you'll not be able to leverage API scopes and IAM permission levels in a normal way.

In terms of coding, to replicate this mechanism inside of a Lambda handler is an anti-pattern. Going down that route one will soon end up with something that looks like the routing for a node express server, not a Lambda function.

After having set up 50+ Lambdas behind API Gateway I can say that
function handlers should be kept as dump as possible, allowing them to be reusable independent from the context from which they're being invoked.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, AWS allows only one handler per Lambda function. That’s why I have created a little "routing" mechanism with Java Generics (for stronger type checks at compile time). In the following example you can **call multiple methods and pass different object types to the Lambda and back via one Lambda handler**:

Lambda class with handler:

```
public class GenericLambda implements RequestHandler<LambdaRequest<?>, LambdaResponse<?>> {

@Override
public LambdaResponse<?> handleRequest(LambdaRequest<?> lambdaRequest, Context context) {

    switch (lambdaRequest.getMethod()) {
    case WARMUP:
        context.getLogger().log("Warmup");  
        LambdaResponse<String> lambdaResponseWarmup = new LambdaResponse<String>();
        lambdaResponseWarmup.setResponseStatus(LambdaResponse.ResponseStatus.IN_PROGRESS);
        return lambdaResponseWarmup;
    case CREATE:
        User user = (User)lambdaRequest.getData();
        context.getLogger().log("insert user with name: " + user.getName());  //insert user in db
        LambdaResponse<String> lambdaResponseCreate = new LambdaResponse<String>();
        lambdaResponseCreate.setResponseStatus(LambdaResponse.ResponseStatus.COMPLETE);
        return lambdaResponseCreate;
    case READ:
        context.getLogger().log("read user with id: " + (Integer)lambdaRequest.getData());
        user = new User(); //create user object for test, instead of read from db
        user.setName("name");
        LambdaResponse<User> lambdaResponseRead = new LambdaResponse<User>();
        lambdaResponseRead.setData(user);
        lambdaResponseRead.setResponseStatus(LambdaResponse.ResponseStatus.COMPLETE);
        return lambdaResponseRead;
    default:
        LambdaResponse<String> lambdaResponseIgnore = new LambdaResponse<String>();
        lambdaResponseIgnore.setResponseStatus(LambdaResponse.ResponseStatus.IGNORED);
        return lambdaResponseIgnore;    
    }
}
}
```

LambdaRequest class:

```
public class LambdaRequest<T> {
private Method method;
private T data;
private int languageID; 

public static enum Method {
    WARMUP, CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE 
}

public LambdaRequest(){
}

public Method getMethod() {
    return method;
}
public void setMethod(Method create) {
    this.method = create;
}
public T getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public int getLanguageID() {
    return languageID;
}
public void setLanguageID(int languageID) {
    this.languageID = languageID;
}
}
```

LambdaResponse class:

```
public class LambdaResponse<T> {

private ResponseStatus responseStatus;
private T data;
private String errorMessage;

public LambdaResponse(){
}

public static enum ResponseStatus {
    IGNORED, IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETE, ERROR, COMPLETE_DUPLICATE
}

public ResponseStatus getResponseStatus() {
    return responseStatus;
}

public void setResponseStatus(ResponseStatus responseStatus) {
    this.responseStatus = responseStatus;
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

}
```

Example POJO User class:

```
public class User {
private String name;

public User() {
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

JUnit test method:

```
    @Test
public void GenericLambda() {
    GenericLambda handler = new GenericLambda();
    Context ctx = createContext();

    //test WARMUP
    LambdaRequest<String> lambdaRequestWarmup = new LambdaRequest<String>();
    lambdaRequestWarmup.setMethod(LambdaRequest.Method.WARMUP);
    LambdaResponse<String> lambdaResponseWarmup = (LambdaResponse<String>) handler.handleRequest(lambdaRequestWarmup, ctx);

    //test READ user
    LambdaRequest<Integer> lambdaRequestRead = new LambdaRequest<Integer>();
    lambdaRequestRead.setData(1); //db id
    lambdaRequestRead.setMethod(LambdaRequest.Method.READ);
    LambdaResponse<User> lambdaResponseRead = (LambdaResponse<User>) handler.handleRequest(lambdaRequestRead, ctx);
    }
```

ps.: if you have **deserialisation problems** (**LinkedTreeMap** cannot be cast to ...) **in you Lambda function** (because uf the Generics/Gson), use the following statement:

```
YourObject yourObject = (YourObject)convertLambdaRequestData2Object(lambdaRequest, YourObject.class);
```

Method:

```
private <T> Object convertLambdaRequestData2Object(LambdaRequest<?> lambdaRequest, Class<T> clazz) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(lambdaRequest.getData());
    return gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way I see, choosing single vs multiple API is a function of following considerations:

1. Security: I think this is the biggest challenge of having a single API structure. It may be possible to have different security profile for different parts of the requirement
2. Think microservice model from business perspective:
   The whole purpose of any API should be serving some requests, hence it must be well understood and easy to use. So related APIs should be combined. For example, if you have a mobile client and it requires 10 things to be pulled in and out from DB, it makes sense to have 10 endpoints into a single API.
   But this should be within reason and should be seen in context of overall solution design. For example, if you design a payroll product, you may think to have separate modules for leave management and user details management. Even if they are often used by a single client, they should still be different API, because their business meaning is different.
3. Reusability: Applies to both code and functionality reusability. Code reusability is a easier problem to solve, ie build common modules for shared requirements and build them as libraries. 
   Functionality reusability is harder to solve. In my mind, most of the cases can be solved by redesigning the way endpoints/functions are laid out, because if you need duplication of functionality that means your initial design is not detailed enough.

Just found a [link](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns/) in another SO post which summarizes better