# Is aws lambda can expose only one spring boot api

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, microservices

I have developed 4 apis using spring boot. Now i m trying to enable aws lambda for serverless. Is it possible to expose 4 api’s with single lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to expose 4 api’s with single lambda.

AWS lambda is `FaaS` - functions as a service, One function per Lambda.

However you can arguably achieve the intended functionality with a wrapper/proxy function as the entry point and route the request to upstream methods/functions as needed

Its described here [aws api gateway & lambda: multiple endpoint/functions vs single endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428226/6785908)

[image]

Take a look at the following documentation on creating an API Gateway => Lambda proxy integration:
[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource)

The following is merely a reworded explanation of what's given here [aws api gateway & lambda: multiple endpoint/functions vs single endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428226/6785908) .

AWS example has a good explanation; A Lambda request like the following:

```
POST /testStage/hello/world?name=me HTTP/1.1
Host: gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
headerName: headerValue

{
    "a": 1
}
```

Will end up sending the following event data to your AWS Lambda function:

```
{
  "message": "Hello me!",
  "input": {
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/hello/world",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "headerName": "headerValue",
      "Host": "gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "Postman-Token": "9f583ef0-ed83-4a38-aef3-eb9ce3f7a57f",
      "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/2.4.5",
      "Via": "1.1 d98420743a69852491bbdea73f7680bd.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "pn-PWIJc6thYnZm5P0NMgOUglL1DYtl0gdeJky8tqsg8iS_sgsKD1A==",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "54.240.196.186, 54.182.214.83",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "name": "me"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "hello/world"
    },
    "stageVariables": {
      "stageVariableName": "stageVariableValue"
    },
    "requestContext": {
      "accountId": "12345678912",
      "resourceId": "roq9wj",
      "stage": "testStage",
      "requestId": "deef4878-7910-11e6-8f14-25afc3e9ae33",
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
        "accountId": null,
        "cognitoIdentityId": null,
        "caller": null,
        "apiKey": null,
        "sourceIp": "192.168.196.186",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
        "userArn": null,
        "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/2.4.5",
        "user": null
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "apiId": "gy415nuibc"
    },
    "body": "{\r\n\t\"a\": 1\r\n}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
}
```

Now you have access to all headers, url params, body etc. So you could use that to handle requests differently in your wrapper/proxy Lambda function and route to upstream functions as per your routing needs.

Many people are using this methodology today as opposed to creating lambda function for each method and an api gateway resource.

There are pros and Cons to this approach

- **Deployment**: if each lambda function is discrete then you can deploy them independently, which might reduce the risk from code changes (microservices strategy). Conversely you may find that needing to deploy functions separately adds complexity and is burdensome.
- **Self Description**: API Gateway's interface makes it extremely intuitive to see the layout of your RESTful endpoints -- the nouns and verbs are all visible at a glance. Implementing your own routing could come at the expense of this visibility.
- **Lambda sizing and limits**: If you proxy all -- then you'll wind up needing to choose an instance size, timeout etc. that will accommodate all of your RESTful endpoints. If you create discrete functions then you can more carefully choose the memory footprint, timeout, deadletter behavior etc. that best meets the needs of the specific invocation.

More on `Monolithic lambda` vs `Micro Lambda` here : https://hackernoon.com/aws-lambda-should-you-have-few-monolithic-functions-or-many-single-purposed-functions-8c3872d4338f