# invoke different lambda function in same endpoint of api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I want to invoke(integrate) lambda function to an API gateway, it should invoke lambda dynamic-based request body or resource policy or authorization.
I have integrated authorization lambda into the same API gateway now I want to invoke different lambda from the same API gateway.
is it possible to invoke different lambda functions in any way?
usually, we integrate one lambda function with one API gateway resource, and once authorization is checked and true we return resource policy or true from the authorization lambda function the actual integrated lambda function invoke but I want dynamic

Comment: Sadly, no. You can't do that.

Comment: You could have one lambda which calls other lambdas.  Use whatever criteria you were planning on using to build logic that calls one lambda or another?

Comment: thank you for answer, this i was thinking also but my manager said no for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One Lambda Function OR Multiple Lambda Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035940/one-lambda-function-or-multiple-lambda-functions)