# Converting ASP.NET API To AWS Lambdas

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-design

I have a asp.net core 3.1 API application that I have been using as my backend api.

I have this application hosted in one AWS Lambda Function, with API Gateway, with one HTTP route and having the ASP.NET Core application handle the routing.

Looking around the web and reading docs, it seems the standard would be to have one HTTP API Route per Lambda Function, (So as I interpreted it would mean having every ASP.NET controller of my API in one lambda function).

Meaning since I have 14 routes it would seems I would need 14 lambda functions with API endpoints. Also this would mean basically no longer having a ASP.NET core API, and disassembling the application.

I have no issues in completing this, just wanted to know if this is actually the correct why and the new normal in developing api's.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, one lambda for endpoint (not per controller)

Comment: So basically no more ASP.NET Core API Application?

Comment: Correct, you are going to throw out most of your application

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to route several endpoints to the same lambda function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428226/11886801). But I believe most people try to use one lambda per endpoint.

As for what you say about the new normal in developing APIs i would caution you to believe the hype too much. Serverless definitely has a place in modern web development but it is not replacing traditional APIs that i have seen where i have worked.