# Lambda AWS function for each endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an application with 3 modules and 25 endpoints (between modules). Modules: Users, CRM, PQR.

I want to optimize AWS costs and generally respect the architecture best practices.

- Should I build a lambda function for each endpoint?
- Does using many functions cost more than using only one?

Comment: Yes/No/Maybe/It depends - there are use cases where either of these answers would be correct, can you tell us more about the use case and what you're trying to optimize for?

Comment: Hi, I want to optimize AWS costs and generally respect the best architecture. Does using many functions cost more than using only one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aws api gateway & lambda: multiple endpoint/functions vs single endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425511/aws-api-gateway-lambda-multiple-endpoint-functions-vs-single-endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

The link in [Gustavos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66478182/6485881) provides a decent starting point. I'll elaborate on that based on the criteria you mentioned in the comments.

You mentioned that you want to optimize for cost and architecture best practices, let's start with the cost component.
Lambda pricing is fairly straightforward and you can check it out on the [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/?nc1=h_ls). Basically you pay for how long your code runs in 1MS increments. How much each millisecond costs depends on how many resources you provision for your Lambda function. Lambda is typically not the most expensive item on your bill, so I'd start optimizing it, once it becomes a problem.

**From a pricing perspective it doesn't really matter if you have fewer or more Lambda functions.**

In terms of architecture best practices, there is no single one-size-fits-all reference architecture, but the post Gustavo mentioned is a good starting point: [Best practices for organizing larger serverless applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/). How you structure your application can depend on many factors:

- Development team size
- Development team maturity/experience (in terms of AWS technologies)
- Load patterns in the application
- Development process
- [...]

You mention three main components/modules with 25 endpoints in total:

- Users
- CRM
- PQR

Since you didn't tell us much about the technology stack, I'm going to assume you're trying to build a REST API that serves as the backend for some frontend application.

In that case you could think of the three modules as three microservices, which implement specific functionality for the application. Each of them implements a few endpoints (combination of HTTP-Method and path). If you start with an API Gateway as the entry point for your architecture, you can use that as an abstraction of the internal architecture for your clients.

The API Gateway can route requests to different Lambda functions based on the HTTP method and path. You can now choose how to implement the backend. I'd probably start off with a common codebase from which multiple Lambdas are built and use the API gateway to map each endpoint to a Lambda function. You can also start with larger multi-purpose Lambdas and refactor them in time to extract specific endpoints and then use the API Gateway to route to the more specialized Lambdas.

You might have noticed, that this is a bit vague and that's on purpose. I think you're going to end up with roughly as many Lambdas as you'll have endpoints, but it doesn't mean you have to start that way. If you're just getting started with AWS, managing a bunch of Lambdas and there interaction can seem daunting. Start with more familiar architectures and then refactor them to be more cloud native over time.

Comment: Excellent contribution, thank you very much. yes, I'm actually going to build a backed

Comment: Cool, if this answered your question, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so future readers know this helps and your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture and how decoupled you want it to be. Here is a good starting point for you to take a look into best practices:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/